# why do you need to have staging and production on the same K8 instance when using Jenkins x

Tags: jenkins-x

So im not seeing why you would want jenkins x to install a staging and production on the same K8 server as itself. Does this not mean every team has its own production?

I could understand having jenkins x and staging on one server, and then have another server for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with Jenkins X, each team has their own [Environments](https://jenkins-x.io/about/features/#environments) like `Staging` and `Production`.

When installing Jenkins X via the [jx create cluster](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/create-cluster/) command we default to creating the teams environments in different namespaces in the kubernetes cluster.

Obviously you could use different clusters for different teams; so each team could use a separate cluster.

There is also a requirement that lots of folks want to use separate clusters (and cloud Service Accounts) for different environments of a team. e.g. the `Dev` environment could be on one cluster, the `Staging` on another cluster and `Production` another one.

We are working on [making multi-cluster configuration easy to setup](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/479) - for now its a manual process.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Would this new feature setup allow for jenkins x to be installed on a completely seperate cluster.. isolated from all environments but allow the pipeline to show the stages of flow.

Comment: after looking into this further, i am interested in knowing how internally the promotion works in jx... i have been reading on gitOps, and most articles mention two orchestration cycles both relying on git as the source of truth.. how does jenkins x fall into place

Comment: @user1555190 yes we should be able to support installing Jenkins X on one cluster and promoting to, say, Staging and Promotion on separate clusters.

Comment: here's how promotion works in Jenkins X: https://jenkins-x.io/faq/develop/#how-does-promotion-actually-work